# vue take dynamic object values

Tags: vue.js, object, dynamic

I am facing an issue with getting values from an object with VueJS.
The object is something like

```
{
"abc": false,
"abd": false,
"feat": [
    {
        "opt1": "5",
        "opt2": "3",
        "opt3": "2",
        "opt4": "7"
    },
    {
        "opt1": "15",
        "opt2": "32",
        "opt3": "21",
        "opt4": "17"
    },
    {
        "opt1": "35",
        "opt2": "33",
        "opt3": "12",
        "opt4": "71"
    },
]
```

}

now, I have defined an Array with those values

```
myArray = ["opt2", "opt4"]
```

I want to parse my Object and get the first record values but only for the attributes from my Array

My code is like this

```
myFunct() {
const returnValue = Object.fromEntries(this.myArray.map(mA => ({
    group: mA,
    value: this.myObj.feat[0].mA
  })))      
  return returnValue
```

}

But my returnValue is undefined
Can someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What value are you expecting to get? Can you present?

Comment: I think I found the issue, it is because I've used fromEntries instead of fromValues. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

This will return an Array of objects:

```
myFunct() {
  return this.myArray.map((mA) => ({
    group: mA,
    value: this.myObj.feat[0][mA],
  });
},
```